# data getting truncated when typecasted to string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

i tried to search solution for this, but didn't get the exact match and thus it couldn't solve my problem.
i have a JSON file, i load it on to a variable called data and i want to convert it into string to put it into some text file. But it is getting truncated when i typecast it to string. is there any way from which i can do it with no truncation?

```
import json
jsonFile = 'check.json'
jsonData = open(jsonFile).read().decode('utf-8-sig')
data = json.loads (jsonData)
fp = open ( r'c:\temp\retrieved Json.txt', 'a')
fp.write ( str(data) )
fp.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by truncated? Can you add the value of data as is, and that of what is written to the file?

Comment: cant add it here, it is thousand lines of content, too big to add here. By truncate i mean, suppose it is of thousand lines of content, when typecasted to string, i'm getting only first 600-700 lines. For small file content, it is working fine, but for very large file it is getting truncated, so is there any limit for it?

Comment: Why are you doing that in the first place?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was thinking that maybe OP is trying to save multiple jsons as a string in a single file, but given his last comment about *thousand lines of content*, I am not so sure anymore..

Comment: i have an application with the text file in which json content is one of the contents of text file

Comment: @mu無: What the OP is doing in that code is questionable at best and completely broken at worst, so we need to hear WTH exactly is going on.

Comment: i have attached just part of the entire code.